# Wordpress plugin add_new_post($info = array()) type function?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add a new blog post from wordpress plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [wp_publish_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_publish_post)

Comment: oh thanks you You can accept an answer in 10 minutes
(click on this box to dismiss)